# Assign name to bower install repo

Tags: bower

If I give a url to bower like `http://something/this/is/javascript` it's going to most likely name the repo `javascript`. My question is, is there any wat to assign a name for a component something like `bower install http://something/this/is/javascript awesome`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can choose the name if you register it in the Bower registry:

```
bower register awesome http://website.com/this/is/javascript
```